# VLC: saving a stream to a file

Tags: vlc

This code works with VLC 2.2.8 but it does not with VLC 3.0.9.2

```
if (it->second.handle  &&  it->second.fDump) {
    // Video/audio + file dump -> duplicate stream
    transcode = "#duplicate{ dst=file{ dst=" + string(it->second.fDump) + " }, dst=display }";
}
else if (it->second.handle == NULL) {
    // No video + file dump -> single stream
    transcode = "#standard{ access=file, dst='" + string(it->second.fDump) + "' }";
}
```

I am focusing on the second branch and I wish to receive suggestions, thanks.

**UPDATE:**

It does not work means that it does not throw any error nor warning but it does not create the file. It seems, it ignores the option.

**UPDATE 2:**

I suspect that the saving option is ignored because I see this line in the application log which is related to the GPU but I have no way to see the video output:

- avcodec: Using OpenGL/VAAPI backend for VDPAU for hardware decoding

It is not required decoding the stream but simply saving.

**UPDATE 3:**

I do not use the graphic interface but the command line and this works:

```
vlc rtsp://172.18.2.60:554/Streaming/Channels/1 --rtsp-user=$user --rtsp-pwd=$passwd \
    --sout="#file{dst=test.mp4}" --vout=dummy -Idummy --ignore-config --quiet \
    --rtsp-frame-buffer-size=500000 --network-caching=4000
```

However, trying to send the same trough VLC library API, it does not save the file. Then the issue should be in this piece of code which works with VLC 2.2.8:

```
it->second.p_lib = libvlc_new((int)argsCount, p_args);
if (!it->second.p_lib) {
    HVLog("Cannot initialize VLC engine");
    return -1;
}

// Set up logging
libvlc_log_set(it->second.p_lib, s_vlc_logcb, nullptr);

libvlc_media_t *p_url = libvlc_media_new_location(it->second.p_lib, url.c_str());
it->second.p_player = libvlc_media_player_new_from_media(p_url);
libvlc_media_release(p_url);

if (it->second.handle)
    libvlc_media_player_set_hwnd(it->second.p_player, it->second.handle);

if (libvlc_media_player_play(it->second.p_player) < 0) {
    HVLog("HVPlayOpen(%p, %d): cannot play stream %s", p_cam, channel, url.c_str());
    return -1;
}

return 0;
```

For testing, I used this code instead and it works, obviously.

```
char vlcstr[1024];
snprintf(vlcstr, 1024, "vlc %s --rtsp-user=%s --rtsp-pwd=%s --sout=#file{dst=%s} --vout=dummy -Idummy "
        "--ignore-config --quiet --rtsp-frame-buffer-size=500000 --network-caching=4000 &",
        ss.str().c_str(), p_camera->getUser().c_str(), p_camera->getPassword().c_str(), it->second.fDump);
HVLog("HVPlayOpen(%p, %d): %s", p_cam, channel, vlcstr);
system(vlcstr);
return 0;
```

However, I wish to use the library API not the system().

**UPDATE 4:**

This is the log https://pastebin.com/9zgMQiNL

Comment: Please update your answer to include how it "doesn't work".  i.e. it throws an error, crashes immediately, etc.  If you've tried any debugging steps yet, put those in as well.  More information gives your question a better chance of being answered.

Comment: Thank you @prieber , I did.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

The issue is addressed using the libvlc_media_add_option() function as show here:

- https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=69933